# How to change values in a dataframe based on another dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have two data frames looking like this:

```
A:
start  end  X
100    200  1
400    550  1
780    900  1
...

B:
time  X
100   0
150   0
200   0
220   0
250   0
300   0
...
```

For every row in A I now want to check if `time` in dataframe B is between `start` and `end` in dataframe A and if so I want to change the value in `X` in B. So the result should look like this:

```
B:
time  X
100   1
150   1
200   1
220   0
250   0
300   0
...
```

I tried to do so in a for-loop and with `mutate` but since my dataframes are huge this was way too slow. Is there a smart R function to achieve this?

Comment: Look at `data.table::foverlaps`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `data.table` join syntax:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(A)
setDT(B)
B[A, on = .(time >= start, time <= end), X := i.X]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I like that approach but I'm not really familiar yet with all of the R syntax. I'm getting the following error when trying this: 
`Error in `[.data.frame`(B, A, on = .(time >= start, time <= end), `:=`(X,  : 
  unused argument (on = .(time >= start, time <= end))`
Could you explain your answer a little bit more so I can try to understand what is happening?

Comment: Nevermind I got it! I needed to add setDT(A) and setDT(B) to (I guess) set the dataframes I created as datatables?

Comment: @Fayre glad you figured it out, I thought for some reason you already had data.tables.

Answer (score 2):

`data.table::foverlaps` efficiently does range-based joins. For it to work, both frames must have a start and end column, which means we need to duplicate `B$time` (it has been suggested to short-cut this process, not yet implemented).

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(A)
setDT(B)
B[, time2 := time]

foverlaps(B, A)
#    start end  X time i.X time2
# 1:   100 200  1  100   0   100
# 2:   100 200  1  150   0   150
# 3:   100 200  1  200   0   200
# 4:    NA  NA NA  220   0   220
# 5:    NA  NA NA  250   0   250
# 6:    NA  NA NA  300   0   300
```

On the face of it, this is the start. Notice that we want to keep the `X` column and bring in `i.X` (originally from `B`) only when `X` is `NA`. We also don't need to keep all of the extra fields, so I'll trim out the extra in the same step:

```r
foverlaps(B, A)[, X := ifelse(is.na(X), i.X, X)][, .(time, X)]
#    time X
# 1:  100 1
# 2:  150 1
# 3:  200 1
# 4:  220 0
# 5:  250 0
# 6:  300 0
```

There are other ways that this can be done, many (most?) of them involve cartesian joins that scale poorly if you have many many rows in both.

Comment: sindri_baldur's answer is more concise and accomplishes the same thing.